# Different "highlighted" color for accessory view based on what was tapped?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios5

My designers have come up with a design that's a bit tricky. In a tableView, they want me to 

1) have a custom accessory view - (UIButton subview) - DONE
2) give a custom action (no detailView pushed to a navigation stack but something else) to a tapped cell accessory - DONE

Now comes the tricky part.

1) If I tap the cell, the accessory view should show a "highlightedBackground".

2) If I tap the accessory view, only the accessory view should highlight, but with "alternativeHighlightedBackground".

So to recap, for the accessoryView, we have normal background and two different highlighted backgrounds, depending on whether the whole cell was tapped, or only the accessory view was tapped.

At the moment, I am adding a UIButton as a subview to the accessory view in cellForRowAtIndexPath, that serves as a custom accessory. Obviously, the accessory view passes the touch event to the button, and the button highlights with the same background, regardless of what was tapped. 
The cell is not custom at the moment, its a normal UITableViewCell instance.
The SDK is iOS5, unfortunately no iOS6 can be used.

Any advice?

Answer (score 1):

I would abandon the accessory view route, and create a subclass of `UITableViewCell`. Simply create you button in the init function, add it as a subview to the `contentView` of the cell, set the buttons's touch-up action to be what ever you want, then override `layoutSubviews` with something that looks like this:

```
- (void)layoutSubviews
{
    [super layoutSubviews];

    CGRect bounds = self.contentView.bounds;

    CGFloat buttonOriginX = self.contentView.bounds.size.width - BUTTON_WIDTH - PAD;
    CGFloat buttonOriginY = floorf((bounds.size.height - BUTTON_HEIGHT)/2.0)+1;

    self.mybutton.frame = CGRectMake(buttonOriginX, buttonOriginY, BUTTON_WIDTH, BUTTON_HEIGHT );
}
```

The button will intercept touches before the cell will this way. You can then be in complete control of what the buttons displays when it is touched (set setting it's highlight state image).

Comment: I experimented a bit with it, basically there is nothing wrong with using accessory view. The REAL problem is knowing when the cell was tapped and when it was not. Based on this, I need to set the highlighted background to one of two versions. The problem is I do not have a reliable way to detect this, and the other thing is I need to set the background back to the default one once the cell is displayed again in the list.

Comment: In the button's action method, set the cell background to the color you want.

Comment: Switching the background is not a problem. I can do it in many ways. As I mentioned, the problem was finding out when the cell was tapped and when the accessory view. Also making sure that when I push this table view onto the stack or show it again after poping some other view that was on top of this, the proper background is set back.
I ended up with overriding 5 methods in the custom cell.